# How should I format my 3D engine's geometry-instantiation process?

Tags: java, 3d, geometry, instantiation

I am currently working on a 3D engine in java and have run across a few problems. Such as, a reliable way to create 3D (or 2D or 1D) geometry in a reliable, simplistic way. Of course, there is no real, straight-forward answer for this, but I'm mainly anticipating this to be a discussion-type-post.. But, nonetheless, I'm looking for a simple, yet reliable way to instantiate geometry in my 3D engine.

(As an example of what exactly it is that I mean, I currently have everything being composed of 3D points (as it is in reality), but telling the engine what the points compose is a difficult task, making it hard to get reliable geometry. I need a more reliable system rather than just using many many points.)

Answer (score 1):

Yay discussion-type question -- first off, just a warning, discussion-type questions tend to be frowned upon at stackoverflow, but I'll pitch in nonetheless:

The first thing that popped into my mind was the [Half-edge Mesh Datastructure](http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml) -- a simple, and powerful-enough-for-everything-I've-needed-so-far structure -- with almost no space-wise superfluous data. This would cover basically all of your mesh structure needs.

Another solution which you'll find in many 3D game engines is the object-tree system (I'm not sure whether that is the correct name), which you;ll find in action in the [python panda3D game engine](http://www.panda3d.org/), Blender (kinda, not that familiar with blender), and so on and so forth. The idea is to have a simple Object3D class, which can contain other Object3D objects at relative positions within. This nested hierarchy works very well with complex systems, where parts come together to form more complex parts of other things. This nested hierarchy also lends itself very well to recursive O(log n) collision algorithms, and recursive frustum culling (for graphics). This is also very easy to code -- I wrote a basic 3D engine using object trees in 11th grade, and let's just say I wasn't exactly a MENSA member back in the day.

In any engine, we'd need some way to compute intersections and so on, so we can do frustum culling, physics collisions, and so on and so forth. The trick I used (very efficient, and just intelligent enough), was the [AABB tree](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/AABB_tree/Chapter_main.html) -- if we already have trees of objects, we simply let every object store & compute its AABB, and hey presto! AABB tree.

Anyways, you say, since I've some experience writing some code like this I must be able to provide samples, right? Yes:

```
public class Object3D {
    public LinkedList<Object3D> children;
    public AABB aabb; // the AABB of the object -- constructed 
                      // by union of children's AABBs
    public void doesIntersect(Object3D obj){
        // intersection using AABB-AABB intersection
        // sadly web resources are sorely lacking, so I shall handle this one below
    }
}
```

**On AAABB-AABB collisions (if you need to know)**
We have two boxes. Each box is aligned with the axes, and each box has a width, height, and depth. To test if they collide, we see whether they overlap when looking along all three axes -- after all, if they don't overlap when we look along even *one* axis, they can't possibly be colliding. Some fancy math later, we note that:

```
"Box A and Box B collide" iff "Box A and B have overlapping x coordinates" and 
"same for y coordinates" and "same for z coordinates" and 
"same for any other dimensions of space you decide to implement".
```

As it turns out, this is a trivial check, both to code and to compute, which is why AABBs make good bounding volumes for object trees.

Well, for a discussion this answer has gotten rather one-sided. Anyways, comments would be lovely, I'm sure there are some useful things I've missed (verlet integration, raytracing, but all of those are easy on a base as described above)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's very informative, but, as unfortunate as it is, I have practically no knowledge on any matter dealing with 3D engines.. Such as the AABB thing, I've heard of it before, but I really don't know anything about it than what you just explained.. As for the Object3D thing you explained, my first attempt at making this engine was a lot like that.. Basically, I had a Geometry3D class with a subclass of Geometry2D which had a subclass of Geometry1D. And, of course, any Geometry1D object was composed of 3D points. (I have a Point3D class, but it was not a subclass of

Comment: Geometry1D.) I started having issues when I tried to get my render engine (I'm making this literally from scratch out of personal preference, so I found the wiki article on perspective projection and used that math, so I can render one point at a time and that's it.) to work with the system because it had no way to tell what points connected what segments connected what polygons connected what polyhedrons and I also had to take into consideration curves, so as I tried to develop the system to be.. better, I found that the code started to loop back on itself and I kept hitting dead ends, so I

Comment: just scratched all that I had except the point renderer and the 3D point class itself. (Also, I have a camera class and the graph itself in which this is all to be displayed, but neither of those really matter to the subject..)

Comment: okay -- so I'll cover some more stuff then -- the idea behind the Object3D is not to represent a single point, but a bunch of them. As for the from scratch and WP:perpective projection stuff, yeah I know that feel

Comment: late response not a problem, but it seems I might have lost my train of thought when I was responding...a bit late to find it now though...